# PsychoPy using KeyList to set up an experiment

Tags: psychopy

I am trying to write a code to set up an experiment that involves: creating a window that presents the numbers 0-9 for 1 second, in order for the user to go onto the next screen they need to press the key that responds to the number presented. I have managed to get the numbers on the screen but unsure on how to use KeyList to get the number presented on screen and user to press same number on screen to move on.

```
from psychopy import visual, core, event

win = visual.Window([1024, 768], fullscr = False, \
    allowGUI=True, units="pix", color = (-1, -1, -1))

for number in ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8','9']:
    tstim= visual.TextStim(win,text = number, pos=(0,0))
    tstim.draw()
    win.flip()
    core.wait(1.0)
    win.flip()
    core.wait(1.0)

win.flip()

event.waitKeys(keyList=['return'])

win.close
```

thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You should avoid `core.wait()`, as you can't do anything during that interval (like continuously check for keypresses, which is (I think) what you want. Also, for better performance, you should create your stimuli just once, and then update their properties as required (i.e. it takes longer to create a text stimulus from scratch than it does to just change the content of an existing one).

Untested, but try something like this:

```
from psychopy import visual, core, event

win = visual.Window([1024, 768], fullscr = False, 
      allowGUI = True, units = 'pix', color = (-1, -1, -1))

# create just once:
tstim = visual.TextStim(win, text = 'blah', pos=(0,0))

correct_key_pressed = False

for number in ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']:
    tstim.text = number

    # assuming a screen refresh rate of 60 Hz, draw
    # the stimulus 60 times (= 1 second duration):
    for frame in range(60):
        tstim.draw()
        win.flip()

        # check for keypresses on every screen refresh:
        keys = event.getKeys()
        if number in keys:
            correct_key_pressed = True
            break # exit this drawing loop

    if correct_key_pressed:
        break # exit the number loop

core.quit()
```

*This isn't very sophisticated: it ignores the reaction time issue (e.g. we should perhaps ignore correct keypresses on the current number if they occur before a physiologically valid interval has elapsed, and instead regard responses to the previous number as correct during that period).*

Comment: Thanks for the help, but the code causes the numbers to change by itself rather than depending on what number the user presses.

Comment: OK, it really isn't so clear to me what the task is. Can you edit your question to explicitly list the set of steps of the stimuli and responses? Think how you would need to communicate it in a methods section of a paper.

Comment: Put the numbers 0-9 on a screen showing for 1 second and then show the next number after the user presses the number key corresponding to the number that was shown, then move onto the next number and so on. Hopefully this makes sense now.